# How to include variable values in the scan(f) function on the SAME line?

Tags: c

Suppose i want to input 4 integers to be assigned to a variable when the program prompts me to. When I type in the first integer and hit ENTER, the marker should STAY on the SAME line and skip a SPACE. The second on would be entered on that same line. Each integer would have one space between them

WHAT function can i use. Please suggest the simplest possible way. (Still a beginner).

```
int num1, num2, num3, num4;
printf("Give values: ");
scanf("%d%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4);
```

Comment: so whats wrong, what error you get? it seems fine to me.

Comment: so you want stay on same line on next entry of number after hit enter?

Comment: If you want to change the way the enter key operates you have a lot of work ahead of you! Are you sure that is necessary??

Comment: Yes I want to stay on same line on next entry of number after hit enter?

Comment: Aside from labeling your space bar as "Enter", there is no simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

The user is pressing enter, and this is being echoed back and starting a new line.

In order to avoid this, you'll need to turn off `echo` (and then read and echo individual characters except for newline). This is system-dependent, for example on Linux you can put the `tty` into `raw/uncooked` mode.

You may find a library such as GNU `readline` that does most of the work for you.